# Concise way to count where two columns are non-null (in select clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider a table with two nullable columns `a` and `b` of any type, and some other arbitrary columns.

I can count cases where one column is not null with:

```
select count(a) from ...
```

I can count cases where *either* column is not null with:

```
select count(coalesce(a, b)) from ...
```

But the only way I've been able to figure out how to count cases where *both* columns are not null is the rather clunky:

```
select sum(iif(a is not null and b is not null, 1, 0)) from ...
```

Is there a more concise way to count if both are not null? If there's no general way, is there a way if both columns are `int`, or if both columns are `nvarchar`?

The reason I don't want to do it in a `where` clause, e.g.:

```
select count(*) from ... where a is not null and b is not null
```

Is that I'm selecting multiple counts from the same subquery at once:

```
select count(*)
      ,count(a)
      ,count(b)
      ,sum(iif(a is not null and b is not null, 1, 0))
from ...
```

And the other reason it needs to take this form is too long to explain here but basically boils down to this being part of a [rather complicated query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/671679) with a very specific structure related to performance.

This question is more out of curiosity, as `sum(iif(...))` *does* work, I'm just wondering if there is something as concise as `coalesce(a, b)` for the *and* case.

This is SQL Server 2016, SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a special case, if both columns are nvarchar,
you could try

```
COUNT(a + b)
```

If data type is interger, then use

```
Count(a/2 + b/2)
```

To avoid overflow error.

Note: a+b is not null only when both a and b are not null

As @JasonC's suggestion, I add another solution for [bitwise operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql) type:

```
Count(a & b)
```

Comment: @JasonC It does not work for mixed `nvarchar` and `int`. For example ` 'abcde'  + 1` is not correct

Comment: Ohhh I guess it only works if it's `nvarchar` but only digits. My [test cases](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/672018) weren't good enough. Btw I'm not *not* accepting this, I'm just giving it time.

Comment: Both your current query and John's answer are working perfectly. I just give an approach :).....

Comment: This does have the possibility of giving an unnecessary arithmetic overflow error if the values can be high.

Comment: Oh hey check it out, for integer types any of the [bitwise operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql) work with no overflow risk, so you can do `COUNT(a & b)`, [for example](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/672250), and don't have to do the (clever, btw) `/2` trick.

Answer (score 1):

A CASE statement should work well here:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN a IS NULL OR b IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END
FROM ...
```

Comment: That is almost as cumbersome as the IIF solution of the OP. I mean this works as well .... but ...

Comment: @rene Cumbersome, perhaps, but clear.  Anything else I can imagine would not be very clear.

Comment: Agreed. Clarity trumps concision. Someone else may need to understand it in future.